# Decryption in a loop with openssl?

Tags: linux, bash, openssl

I'm trying to use openssl to decrypt files. I can successfully encrypt them in a loop, but when I try to change the command to make it decrypt, I get "error reading input file."

```
for f in /dir1/dir2/*.txt ;
  do [ -f $f ] && openssl aes-256-cbc enc -in $f -out $f.enc -k PASSWORD ;
done

!the above works for encrypting

for f in /dir1/dir2/*.txt.enc ;
  do [ -f $f ] && openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k PASSWORD -in $f -out $f;
done


"error reading input file"
```

So I've tried making the input file $f.txt.enc, and $f.enc, and similar fiddling with the outfile. No luck.

Comment: `-in $f -out $f`  ... do you really want to overwrite the input file, for holding output?  That could be the problem.

Comment: @DarrenSmith I'm fine with overwrite, but when I remove "-in $f -out $f" from the command I get the same error.

Comment: did you try:  `-in $f -out ${f}.out ` ?   Maye its not a problem with file overwriting then ... perhaps problem is with usage of encrypt & decrypt commands.

Comment: Yeah that yields the same error. It could be a case of me not understanding the decrypt command process well enough. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I think your encoding line has problem, missing `-` in front of the `aes` part  ... for reference here are lines that work for me:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc    -in $f      -out $f.enc -k PASSWORD 

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in $f.enc  -out $f.dec -k PASSWORD
```